# My player is not moving Using transform.position in Unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D game in Unity. So I used trasform.position += movePos type code to move my player when specific key pressed. I also made some animations. Player is not moving still animation is performing. Everything was working fine before I made the jump animation. But now it isn't working. Can someone suggest me what to do. I hadn't made a repository of code in github so I can't share it.

Here you can watch video what is happening:- https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnUoIDNJEoVSmQylzexBqmA1i8Ur?e=4FhJ5h

and here is my player controls code which is responsible for controls:-

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region variables
    // Private variables
    private float speed = 15f;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool isOnGround;
    private Quaternion leftMoveRotate = new Quaternion(0f, 180f, 0f, 1f);
    private Quaternion rightMoveRotate = new Quaternion(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);

    // Public Variables
    public Animator playerAnimator;
    #endregion
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("ground"))
        {
            isOnGround = true;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (horizontalInput > 0)
        {
            DInput();
        }
        if (horizontalInput < 0)
        {
            AInput();
        }
        playerAnimator.SetFloat("isRunning", Mathf.Abs(horizontalInput));
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        if (isOnGround)
        {
            transform.position += new Vector3(0f, 4f, 0f); // Jump code
            isOnGround = false;
        }
    }
    private void DInput()
    {
        transform.rotation = rightMoveRotate;
        transform.position += new Vector3(0.5f, 0f, 0f) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
    private void AInput()
    {
        transform.rotation = leftMoveRotate;
        transform.position -= new Vector3(0.5f, 0f, 0f) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
}
```

I also have a code of camera following the player and here is that:-

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float offSetX = 5f;
    public float offSetY = 2.5f;
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        Vector3 tempPos = transform.position;
        tempPos.x = player.position.x;
        tempPos.x += offSetX;

        tempPos.y = player.position.y;
        tempPos.y += offSetY;

        transform.position = tempPos;
    }
}
```

and if I remove jump animation from Animator all control works fine. Here is video you can check:-
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AnUoIDNJEoVSmQ2k_o7Fbs0J5_8d?e=tJlayZ

Comment: Something looks really weird with how your Quaternions are set up.

Comment: what are you want to say? I can't understand

Comment: Quaternions have a magnitude of 1, and yet you have 180f in the constructor. So I'm very confused.

Comment: That is used to rotate. 180f is y rotation that works fine before I make jump animation

Comment: Quaternions are 4 dimensional objects.  the "y" value is not what you think it is.

Comment: i know quaternions. (float x, float y, float z, float w). I saw this using making my variable public and in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Maybe the constructor normalizes the quaternion... I dunno.  Still looks very odd to me

Comment: But even if it normalizes the quaternion, the 180f still makes no sense.

Comment: 180 looks like you try to deal with angular values. But quaternions are not angular - it's vector. 100 or 200 would be strange, but ok, but 180 makes me suspect you to understand quaternions wrong. In addition, normalized quaternions are much faster to calculate, so its always better to keep them normalized.

Comment: In general, your code should work. Probably, you have some editor-related issues, like wrong physics setup.
When you capture a video, don't maximaze your window - this way you just hide many important information in inspector, and, please, select the problematic object - show us it's inspector during runtime.
Few notes below:

Comment: 1. Your jump code should immediately, in one frame, move your character 4 meters up. Pretty unusual behaviour, is it what you want to have? Do you use physics/rigidbody/gravity? How you plan to land back on a ground?

Comment: 2. If you call some code from Update(), and do some transformations, you shouldn't use Time.fixedDeltaTime - it's for FixedUpdate(). Use Time.deltaTime instead.

Comment: 3. Do not setup quaternions manually, while you don't really understand it inside out. Use provided methids instead:                                       

- set quaternion from euler angles: `transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);`
- or even use Vector3/Transform, look left: `transform.LookAt(transform.position + Vector3.forward, Vector3.up);` or right: `transform.LookAt(transform.position + Vector3.back, Vector3.up);`

Comment: These doesn't matter. If I remove Jump from animator it works totally fine

Comment: New video added. You can check for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you might have messed up and is not showing in script, is you recorded transform position change in your animation and animation is messing with position.

Comment: I added a video. This may tell you more

Comment: YEa you mentioned that when you remove animation everything starts working so you either recorded doing something with transform position while making animation or you are animating object that is responsible for moving instead of its child.Make that character a child of empty object " Player" have movement script move that  new object you created, Then while having  object " Player" add animation.BUT animate children of this object( actual sprites)".

Comment: I changed some things of transform. And now its working well